# installing .net core 3 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 amd64

Tags: ubuntu, dotnet-framework

I have ubuntu server 18.04.3 amd64.
this is my script to install .net core 3:

```
curl -SL -o dotnet.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/master/dotnet-sdk-latest-linux-arm64.tar.gz
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet
sudo tar -zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet
sudo ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
```

this is my target framework:

```
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
```

when I try to run my project I get the error with `dotnet run` or `dotnet build` I get:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/dotnet: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Thanks

Comment: The .Net Core download you are getting in your CURL command is for arm64, not amd64.  Two very very different platforms.

Comment: @Moo There is no amd64 https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0 thanks

Comment: You want x64 in that page - that’s amd64.